# Schedule reminder test not working - execute now for job not working

Tags: scheduled-reminders, scheduled-job

So I have set up a scedule reminder and made sure it is only dirrected to my email. When I go into sceduled jobs and execute the send_reminder job, it doesn't work. I worked twice yesterday to a collegues email but hasn't work since to either mine or theirs. Is there any way to fix this? Or any reason it wouldn't work? Is there another way to send out emails to custemer a certain length of time after a specific date?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall scheduled job execution wont send the reminder if its not due, what are the settings for your reminder?